# CharacterSet containing all variation of letters

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, uitextfield

I'm working on a registration form where the user has to enter their full name, meaning that the only **acceptable characters for this specific textfield should be (A-Z, a-z)** plus " " (space) but no numbers, nor special caracter such -`+¨¨_{ etc. It should also **accept accents**, such as: [à, é, û] and all other combinations for all letters.

What I have right now is:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters {

    NSMutableCharacterSet *mySet = [NSMutableCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZñ. "];

    return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[mySet invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound);
}
```

Which works fine but doesn't include the accented characters that I need to support, and I'm sure there should be simpler way of including the missing characters without having to type them one at a time.

Comment: The easiest solutionis to remove diacritics from `characters` first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429798/pletter-and-nsregularexpression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the specific character set with all letters, including all diacritics?

```
NSMutableCharacterSet *mySet = [[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[mySet addCharactersInString:@" "];

return ([characters rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[mySet invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound);
```

This will not only cover all diacritics, it will also cover all non-english letters, e.g. the Russian alphabet.

Comment: Damn... On the simulator it wasn't working properly I just tried it on the device and it is but this doesn't include the chacacter " " (space) that should also be allowed

Comment: Just add it to the character set then (edited). You can also add the whole `whitespaceCharacterSet`.

Comment: @Sulthan: Great answer, works perfectly. Do you mind explaining it a bit though?

Comment: @TejasK I am not sure what needs explaining. A set with all characters, we add space character to that set, then we check whether the string contains a character from the inverted set...

Comment: @Sulthan - How does inverting letterCharacterSet allow to use accented characters ? How does it still allow using letters even after applying `invertedSet `

Comment: Yup I was using an UnMutable CharSet... thanks a lot @Sulthan

Comment: @TejasK it's a double negative. The expression means that we haven't found (`NSNotFound`) any other (`inverted`) letters.